# SAPUI5 addEventListener calls function on load not on declared event

Tags: javascript, sapui5, listener, dom-events

I have a function in my controller that targets a button, then attaches an event listener, which should call a function on the click event but it is calling it automatically when the page loads.

How do I change this to only call the function when I click on goBtn?

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var goBtn = document.getElementById('__xmlview1--smartFilterId-btnGo');
    console.log("goBtn = ", goBtn); 
    goBtn.addEventListener("click", this._onGoClick(event), false);
},

_onGoClick: function(event) {
    console.log("Event attaaaaached!!! = ", event);
    // do something else
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are already evaluating your event handler. This calls the `_onGoClick` method immediately (as soon as this line is reached).

```
goBtn.addEventListener("click", this._onGoClick(event), false);
```

What you want to do is pass a function to `addEventListener` that gets called later.

```
goBtn.addEventListener("click", this._onGoClick, false);
```

---

On a different note your code is meant to break in the near future. The id `__xmlview1--smartFilterId-btnGo` is dynamically created and can change as soon as you launch the app in a different context.